# Powershell - Run Shortcut as Admin doesn't work (Windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

i put an shortcut in shell:startup
if i deactivate **"run as Administrator"** the shortcut works fine
[image]
But with admin rights (i need them) it wont show up
[image]

**Thats the shortcut-proberties:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Execute_Windows_Update.ps1"
```

**Execute_Windows_Update.ps1:**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate

Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
```

Comment: Not using W11 but in W10 I always setup a Scheduled Task set with highest privileges to run the Powershell script then call the scheduled task from the Shortcut. Ex: C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /TN "Task Name goes Here!". I'd also recommend the use of -File vs -Command when running a script.

Comment: thanks, ok do you know whats the problem here? seems like the commands arent executed or not found for a reason

Comment: Why File instead of Command?

Comment: -File vs -Command because you are executing a File not issuing a single command. -Command will work though but I find -File more logical and effective. Some previous use of -Command didn't work as expected and the use of -File was pointed out to me.

Comment: got it - you are right, this is more logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not allow startup items to UAC elevate. This was strictly enforced in Vista

> Error message when you start a Windows Vista-based computer: "[Windows has blocked some startup programs](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/930367)"

This was relaxed a bit in 7 but some things are still probably blocked to prevent a flooding of UAC prompts at startup.

The task scheduler is a way around this.

Comment: Thanks - i didn't get an notification about my script being blocked, is there a way to check if it is really blocked by windows 10/11? Some sort of simple command or log-file?

Comment: Not sure, the UI was removed in 7.

Comment: if someone knows if there is a possibility for checking if a command or File is blocked by system on startup - please share your knowledge here